# RichTextBox SelectionLength zero when Selecting outside Text Property

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to wrap my head around a behaviour in WinForms RichTextBox.

When you are using the RichTextBox and select the right end of the RichTextBox it is possible by holding shift and pushing right to select an additional character to the right.

What really boggles my mind is that the SelectionLength property of the RichTextBox is 0.
If you look at it it visually it appears you have a selection of 1 character length that starts from the end of your current Text. if you look at the curSelStart and curSelEnd properties curSelStart starts from the end of your Text property and curSelEnd one character beyond it.

We are working with our own subclass of a Winforms RichTextBox that has all manners of special behaviour implemented and among them we have an assumption that if you press backspace with a SelectionLength of 0 you will erase a character. In this case this assumption is no longer true as pressing backspace will just erase your current Selection.

Any ideas as to why it behaves this way? Any way around it?

Comment: found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231830/richtextbox-undo-adding-spaces which is similar to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour started giving us trouble when we started using our custom RichTextBox control with MultiLine enabled. Thus this got upgraded from an odd behavour I've observed to a bug I had to solve.

it seems to be a quirk in how RichTextBox handles linebreaks. at the end of each line there will always be a '\n' char. That is the mystery character I described in my question above. If you attempt to remove it it will be promptly readded.

With this knowlegde I could make a check if property SelectedText ends with a '\n' char and if the new text I inserted didn't contain a '\n' I would be sure that I needed to add an additional char to my offset my custom control required.

I can't believe that I didn't notice the '\n' earlier. Oh well.. The problem is resolved now.